# Load form with tabs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I need to load a form with dynamyc tabs reading a XML which determines the number of tabs.
I have a 'tab template' and each tab is written with this code.
The first problem is with the id's of the fields. If I have 2(or more) tabs, each tab fields has the same id's and I can't get/set them.

For create tabs, I use the html function like this:

```
var divtab1 = $("#tab1").html();
var tabCode = "<div id='tab"+ i +"' class='tab_content'> "+ divtab1 +"</div>";
finalhtml = finalhml + tabCode;
```

where #tab1 is the 'tab template' and I do this for each tab.
Finally I put finalhtml in a div.

```
$("#bodyTabs").html(finalhtml);
```

The tabs are built well, but some functions like datepickers and ckeditors(text editor) doesn't work.

I don't know how change field id's dynamically and don't know if this way is the best for do that.

Any suggestion?

A lot of thanks!

Comment: tab_class is only for view design

Comment: @Arnau :not working? means you can't access that controls from clientside or serverside? or is not rendering? pls explain?

Comment: I use ASP MVC in Visual Studio, that's view code and I can't read in Controller class .cs

I think that I have the solution using c# in view with <% %> building each tab with a 'for' iteration.

I'm trying it and if works I'll post the solution.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find one good solution. using c# I build a for and each iteration i do:

```
<%     List<String> Idiomas = loadIdiomas();
       foreach (String idioma in Idiomas)
       { %>
       <div id="tab_<%=idioma%>" class="tab_content">
            <input type="text" name="<%=idioma%>_title" id="<%=idioma%>_title"  />
             ...
```

In this way I have different id fields for each tab avoiding use javascript. It is more elegant and the problem of datepickers and text editors is solved.

Thanks all for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

`$('#ID').attr('id', 'ID2');`

to change id

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we use date picker or any editor we have to intialize those on document ready event.
Hence i would suggest that whenever you change the tab content, just call the Init methods of the respected controller and things would work as expected.

Cheers